# Alphatransparent PNG over selectable form fields (sliding envelope)

Tags: css, forms, png, selectable

I'm building the contact form of a portfolio website. I wanted to have an envelope at the bottom of the page from which the contact form comes sliding out as the user scrolls down. I did this by creating three layers (absolute positioned DIVs) on top of eachother, from bottom to top:

- `#envelopeBack` (Containing only a [background image](http://pbeckers.be/img/envelopeBack.png))
- `#envelopeContents` (Containing the actual contact form)
- `#envelopeFront` (Containing only a [background image](http://pbeckers.be/img/envelopeFront.png))

The foreground image is an alphatransparent PNG file. I then wrote some jQuery to set both the `#envelopeBack` and `#envelopeFront` to `position: fixed` at the right time and expand the height of the `#envelopeContents` to make it appear as if it were sliding out of the envelope.

The effect is working well, but as expected the `#envelopeFront` layer blocks out all interaction with the underlying contact form in `#envelopeContents` (i.e. you can't click any button, select any field, etc). I countered this by using `pointer-events: none`, but that only works in [some browsers](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) (Works in Chrome but not in IE for example).

Is there a way to have this working across all "major browsers"? Is there perhaps a better way to implement this sliding-envelope effect? I've copy-pasted some of the relevant code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9c7CM/). I've also applied a red `background-color` to the `#envelopeFront` to show which parts it is hiding (CSS line 34). The `pointer-events: none` is situated at CSS line 38. As for the "major browsers":

- Chrome (Newest version is OK)
- Firefox (Newest version is OK)
- Safari (Version 5+)
- Internet Explorer (8+, though I'd be willing to settle for 9+ as well)

Thanks in advance!